# Replace value in column depending on c=number of characters

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with one column:

```
V1
123
14321
1
65433
56
```

I want to substitute each value in that column with 2 and 1 depending ion number of characters in value: if there is < 3 characters, than its 1, if >= 3 that its 2. SO desired result is:

```
V1
2
2
1
2
1
```

How could i do that? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
df$V1 <- with(df, ifelse(nchar(V1) < 3, 0, 1))
```

Comment: I get the expected output with your code as well.  Can you show the `dput` of example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just coerce to integer

```
df$V1 <- +(nchar(df$V1) >=3)
df$V1
#[1] 1 1 0 1 0
```

---

If the column is `factor`, then `nchar` won't work.  It needs to be converted to `character`

```
df$V1 <- +(nchar(as.character(df$V1)) >=3)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(123L, 14321L, 1L, 65433L, 56L)),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```